# How make Application work with 2 different versions of a DLL

Tags: c#, .net, version, .net-assembly

if you are creating an application on a PC with .NET 4 (first release) and let it run on a second with the lastest .NET 4 Version or the first pc was update to the lastest version of .NET 4 without recompiling it. Then the application still works.

How that works?

kind regards

Comment: It takes very, very careful attention to backwards compatibility.  Something that Microsoft in general is pretty famous for.

Answer (score 0):

Newer Version of the .Net Framework are just adding functions and keeping the "old" functions the same.

If you install newer versions of the .Net Framework they include the older versions.